# Restoring removed frequently visited tile in mobile Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, android

I have inadvertently removed a frequently visited tile from my new-tab page and would like to have it back.

This is very similar problem as presented in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/361950/how-can-i-restore-a-removed-most-visited-site-in-chrome-15), however I am on a tablet and need a solution for mobile Chrome: no bar at the bottom offers "restore all" when a frequently visited site is removed (only a "restore item" notification that displays for 2 seconds and restores the one just-now-removed).